# "iisnode encountered an error when processing the request" even permission is given

Tags: angular, iis, server-side-rendering, iisnode

I am using iisnode to host Angular SSR Project.
Server: Windows Server 2016
IIS : IIS V10

I have given Full access permission to Angular folder for USER, IIS_IUSER, Network

Website work properly for some hours, but after it again show following error.

```
iisnode encountered an error when processing the request.

HRESULT: 0x2
HTTP status: 500
HTTP subStatus: 1002
HTTP reason: Internal Server Error
You are receiving this HTTP 200 response because 
system.webServer/iisnode/@devErrorsEnabled configuration setting is 'true'.

In addition to the log of stdout and stderr of the node.exe process, consider using debugging and ETW traces to further diagnose the problem.

You may get additional information about this error condition by logging stdout and stderr of the node.exe process.To enable logging, set the system.webServer/iisnode/@loggingEnabled configuration setting to 'true' (current value is 'false').
```

How do I permanently solve this problem ?

When I log error:

```
    Error: Failed to lookup view "index" in views directory "C:\....\dist\browser"
    at Function.render (C:\....\server.js:12388:17)
    at ServerResponse.render (C:\....\server.js:24812:7)
    at app.get (C:\....\server.js:142:9)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\....\server.js:15832:5)
    at next (C:\....\server.js:14753:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\....\server.js:14728:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\....\server.js:15832:5)
    at C:\....\server.js:14228:22
    at param (C:\....\server.js:14301:14)
    at param (C:\....\server.js:14312:14)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your application pool doesn't have enough permissions to write or read to the current folder.

I suggest you could check the project folder properties security tab to make sure the IIS AppPool\ has the perission to write or read the folder.

Details, you could refer to this steps:

1.Open Windows Explorer

2.Select the directory the Smartcrypt Manager is installed under (eg: c:\web\mds)

3.Right click the directory and select Properties

4.Select the Security tab

5.Click the Edit button and then Add button

6.Click the Locations button and make sure that you select your computer.

7.Enter IIS AppPool\ (eg: IIS AppPool\smartcrypt) in the Enter the object names to select: text box.

8.Click the Check Names button and click OK.

9.Check Modify under the Allow column, and click OK, and OK.

If this still couldn't solve your issue, I suggest you could try to set the system.webServer/iisnode/@loggingEnabled configuration setting to 'true' and check the logs to see the details error message.

Comment: Thanks for you help, I have done the changes you mansion in you answer, but after some hours it again so me the same error, I updated my question with log, please check